# How to ask a SwiftUI View to display a different @Published var in its List?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mvvm, swiftui

In a multi-language app I have word lists stored in Core Data.

The words are displayed in 4 different SwiftUI `List`s:

[image: screenshot]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let labels = [
        "en": " EN",
        "de": " DE",
        "ru": " RU"
    ]

    let rare1 = [
        "en": "Q",
        "de": "Q",
        "ru": "Ъ"
    ]

    let rare2 = [
        "en": "X",
        "de": "Y",
        "ru": "Э"
    ]

    @AppStorage("language") var language:String = "en"
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack() {
                Picker(selection: $language, label: Text(labels[language]!)) {
                    ForEach(labels.sorted(by: <), id: \.key) { key, value in
                        Text(value).tag(key)
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                
                List {
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                                    WordView(language: language,
                                             predicate: NSPredicate(format: "length(%K) = %d",
                                                                    #keyPath(WordEntity.word), 2))) {
                        Text("letters-2")
                    }

                    NavigationLink(destination:
                                    WordView(language: language,
                                             predicate: NSPredicate(format: "length(%K) = %d",
                                                                    #keyPath(WordEntity.word), 3))) {
                        Text("letters-3")
                    }

                    NavigationLink(destination:
                                    WordView(language: language,
                                             predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                                                    #keyPath(WordEntity.word),
                                                                    rare1[language]!))) {
                        Text("rare-letter-1")
                    }

                    NavigationLink(destination:
                                    WordView(language: language,
                                             predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                                                    #keyPath(WordEntity.word),
                                                                    rare2[language]!))) {
                        Text("rare-letter-2")
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("app-title")
        }.environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: language))
    }
}
```

The 4 `List`s display the same word list, but filtered by different condition:

- A list of 2-lettered words
- A list of 3-lettered words
- A list of words containing Q
- A list of words containing X

So I pass a different `NSPredicate` argument to the same custom `View`:

```
struct WordView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: WordViewModel
    
    init(language: String, predicate: NSPredicate) {
        _vm = StateObject(wrappedValue: WordViewModel(language: language,
                                                      predicate: predicate))
    }

    var body: some View {
        if vm.isLoading {
            ProgressView("is-loading")
        } else {
            List {
                ForEach(vm.wordEntities) { word in
                    WordRow(wordEntity: word)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I pass the `NSPredicate` argument further down to the same View Model:

```
class WordViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var wordEntities: [WordEntity] = []
    @Published var isLoading = false

    init(language: String, predicate: NSPredicate) {
        updateWordEntities(language: language, predicate: predicate)
        fetchWordModels(language: language, predicate: predicate)
    }
```

And finally the above View Model fetches the big word list from the backend URL, stores it into Core Data and then (now comes the problematic part!) stores the filtered list into the *same* `@Published var wordEntities`.

I think it is not a perfect setup and it would be better to have 4 different `@Published` variables in my View Model:

```
@Published var wordsWith2Letters: [WordEntity] = []
@Published var wordsWith3Letters: [WordEntity] = []
@Published var wordsWithRareLetter1: [WordEntity] = []
@Published var wordsWithRareLetter2: [WordEntity] = []
```

However I do not know how to implement it.

I do not know how to say in SwiftUI "now please display the @Published var wordsWith2Letters":

```
List {
    ForEach(vm.wordsWith2Letters) { word in
        WordRow(wordEntity: word)
    }
}
```

and then (depending on user's choice) say to the *same* SwiftUI View "now display the other @Published var wordsWithRareLetter1":

```
List {
    ForEach(vm.wordsWithRareLetter1) { word in
        WordRow(wordEntity: word)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand what the problem is with having 4 @Published properties in one view model instead of one property in 4 view model instances. But neither am I sure why the current solution isn’t good enough if you move the download from backend to a separate class to make sure only one download per language is done

Comment: Joakim my problem with 4 @Published properties is that I don't know how to selected them in the SwiftUI syntax `List {
    ForEach(vm.wordsWith2Letters) { word in
        WordRow(wordEntity: word)
    }
}` because the View is the same. I.e. how to switch between them (depending on the user choice in navigation list) and use the same `View`?

Comment: Ok but if you use this 4 in 1 solution then you have only one instance of the view model so why not pass the correct array (property) to the view instead of the view model.

Comment: Do you mean I could pass `$wordsWith2Letters` or similar? My problem is that in the top `ContentView` I do not have access to the `WordViewModel` which is created in the `WordView`. How to do it?

Comment: Create it in the ContentView with only the language as argument